# Can't write a Show instance for this type

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Consider the following type declaration:

```
data Foobar x = Foo (x (Foobar x))
```

Now write a `Show` instance for that. I dare you!

I casually wrote `deriving Show`, expecting GHC to do it's thing. But it complained that it couldn't do it. "Poor simpleton", I thought, and proceeded to define it myself. But... um... oh, actually that's quite interesting... Clearly `Foobar x` is only showable when `x y` is showable for showable `y`... or... something like that... aaargh!

Now I'm sure I cannot possibly be the first person to define a type such as this. And I can't be the first person to want a `Show` instance for it. So somebody must have figured out how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just specify the obvious constraint – and add some necessary language pragmas – everything works just fine.  For `Foobar` to be showable, the field of `Foo` must be showable, so we require a `Show (x (Foobar x))` constraint.  And if we ask for that, everything just works out:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances, StandaloneDeriving #-}

data Foobar x = Foo (x (Foobar x))
deriving instance Show (x (Foobar x)) => Show (Foobar x)
```

Then:

```
λ> print $ Foo [Foo [], Foo [Foo []]]
Foo [Foo [],Foo [Foo []]]
λ> data SL a = S String | L [a] deriving Show
λ> print $ Foo (L [Foo (S "a"), Foo (L [Foo (S "b"), Foo (L []), Foo (S "c")])])
Foo (L [Foo (S "a"),Foo (L [Foo (S "b"),Foo (L []),Foo (S "c")])])
```

I'm a little bit surprised this works, but not overly so :-)

---

Incidentally, this is exactly what GHC asks of you if you try to derive `Show` for `Foobar`:

```
λ> data Foobar x = Foo (x (Foobar x)) deriving Show

<interactive>:2:45:
    No instance for (Show (x (Foobar x)))
      arising from the first field of ‘Foo’ (type ‘x (Foobar x)’)
    Possible fix:
      use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
        so you can specify the instance context yourself
    When deriving the instance for (Show (Foobar x))
```

All we had to do was use `StandaloneDeriving` and specify exactly that constraint!

---

Also, to be clear, the `StandaloneDeriving` part is optional – it's not doing any magic, and the instance isn't too hard to write by hand:

```
instance Show (x (Foobar x)) => Show (Foobar x) where
  showsPrec p (Foo x) = showParen (p > app_prec) $
                          showString "Foo " . showsPrec (app_prec + 1) x
    where app_prec = 10 :: Int
```

Comment: That's [how `Show` is defined for `Fix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-4.1.2/docs/src/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#Fix) in recursion-schemes.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense – because this *is* `Fix`, up to renaming!  I should have noticed that immediately :-)

Comment: I was sure this type was already in the libraries somewhere, but I couldn't see it for some reason...

Answer (score 6):

Here is how to do it with no extensions:

```
data Foobar x = Foo (x (Foobar x))

class Show1 f where
    showsPrec1 :: Show a => Int -> f a -> ShowS

instance Show1 f => Show (Foobar f) where
    showsPrec n (Foo v) = ("Foo " ++) . showsPrec1 n v -- doesn't handle n correctly because that's not the point of the question and would only distract from the actual important idea
```

The `Show1` class (and some instances for standard types) is also available [on Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/prelude-extras-0.4.0.3/docs/Prelude-Extras.html#t:Show1). The module that defines it uses a few extensions -- but only to reduce boilerplate, and not to enable anything that boring old Haskell2010 can't do.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so while playing with the code, I found **a** way of doing it:

```
instance (Functor f, Show (f String)) => Show (Foobar f) where
  show = fold show

fold :: Functor f => (f x -> x) -> Foobar f -> x
fold f (Foo x) = f (fmap (fold f) x)
```

There's a couple of problems though.

- It doesn't produce exactly the right output. (The `Foo` constructor is missing, and subexpressions get quoted.)
- It apparently requires `UndecidableInstances` to work. (!)
- I tried to change `show` to include the `Foo` constructor, but then GHC panicked (!!!)

I didn't know you could actually *crash GHC* just by writing user code... apparently you can do that.

```
ghc: panic! (the 'impossible' happened)
  (GHC version 7.4.2 for i386-unknown-mingw32):
    kindFunResult ghc-prim:GHC.Prim.*{(w) tc 34d}

Please report this as a GHC bug:  http://www.haskell.org/ghc/reportabug
```

I guess it's called "undecidable" for a reason! o_O

Comment: That panic has nothing to do with (the correct behavior of) `UndecidableInstances` – the worst `UndecidableInstances` can do (or at least, should be able to do!) is make the type checker loop.  I'd say to report that as a bug, but you're apparently on a pretty old GHC version.  If you edit this to include the code that panics, I can test it on a more recent GHC.

Comment: OK, thanks.  Good news: I couldn't reproduce a panic with your code under GHC 7.10.2 on Mac OS X 10.10.5.

Comment: Change `fold show` to `fold (\ x -> "Foo (" ++ show x ++ ")")`. It panics 7.4.2. I tried it with 7.6.x and it didn't panic, so I'm pretty sure whatever this bug is, it's long since been fixed.

Comment: That's truly bizarre o_O.  But at least it's fixed!  (Confirmed on 7.10.2.)